# Training loss and accuracy remain constant after adding attention mechanism

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I trained bidirectional lstm on imdb dataset for sentiment analysis using keras and tensorflow as backend. [This](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/imdb_bidirectional_lstm.py) is the example in keras. After training accuracy quickly jumps to 90% and above for training and 84% for validation. So, far so good.
 But when I create a custom layer of attention decoder and train the network, the training and validation stays constant from epoch 1 to 10.
Below is my code for training on imdb dataset having implemented a custom layer of attention decoder.

```
max_features = 20000
maxlen = 80
batch_size = 32
timesteps = 80
print('Loading data...')
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = imdb.load_data(num_words=max_features)

x_train = x_train[:5000]
y_train = y_train[:5000]
x_test = x_test[:5000]
y_test = y_test[:5000]

print('Pad sequences (samples x time)')
x_train = sequence.pad_sequences(x_train, maxlen=maxlen)
x_test = sequence.pad_sequences(x_test, maxlen=maxlen)
print (x_train[0])          #Shape(5000, 80)
print (y_train[0])          #Shape (5000,)


print('Build model...')
encoder_units=64
decoder_units=64
n_labels=1
trainable=True
return_probabilities=False

def modelnmt():
    input_ = Input(shape=(80,), dtype='float32')
    print (input_.get_shape())
    input_embed = Embedding(max_features, 128 ,input_length=80)(input_)
    print (input_embed.get_shape())
    rnn_encoded = Bidirectional(LSTM(encoder_units, return_sequences=True),
        name='bidirectional_1',
        merge_mode='concat')(input_embed)
    print (rnn_encoded.get_shape())
    y_hat = AttentionDecoder(decoder_units,
        name='attention_decoder_1',
        output_dim=n_labels,
        return_probabilities=return_probabilities,
        trainable=trainable)(rnn_encoded)
    y_adec = Reshape((80,))(y_adec)
    y_hat = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(y_adec)
    model = Model(inputs=input_, outputs=y_hat)
    model.summary()

    return model

model = modelnmt()

# try using different optimizers and different optimizer configs
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

print('Train...')
model.fit(x_train, y_train,
          batch_size=batch_size,
          epochs=10,
          validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
```

And here is the output:

---

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         (None, 80)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
embedding_1 (Embedding)      (None, 80, 128)           2560000   
_________________________________________________________________
bidirectional_1 (Bidirection (None, 80, 128)           98816     
_________________________________________________________________
attention_decoder_1 (Attenti (None, 80, 1)             58050     
_________________________________________________________________
reshape_1 (Reshape)          (None, 80)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 81        
=================================================================
Total params: 2,716,947
Trainable params: 2,716,947
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
Epoc 1/10
5000/5000 [==============================] - 289s - loss: 0.6955 - acc: 0.5056 - val_loss: 0.6935 - val_acc: 0.4956
Epoch 2/10
5000/5000 [==============================] - 348s - loss: 0.6944 - acc: 0.4956 - val_loss: 0.6936 - val_acc: 0.4956
```

I will explain model in short.First the words are embedded and then passed to bidirectional LSTM later to attention decoder. So, what attention decoder does it that it outputs for number of timesteps one number i.e. (None, 80, 1). This `number is then reshaped` and passed to `Dense Layer` to calculate `overall sentiment of the sentence` (probability). The output from attention decoder can later be used for visualizing contribution of each word in the sentence.
What can be `possible reasons for such output?`